# Netbeans not loading a class at run time

Tags: java, netbeans-7, dynamic-loading

I am moving a Java application to Netbeans platform.  One of the function uses the SAXBuilder in the Xerces library for parsing XML.

Declaration of SAXBuilder

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder("org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser", true);
```

This line causes a JDOM Exception (i guess because it could not load the specified parser) :

```
builder.build(xmlFile);
```

The error message is :

> Could not load org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser: SAX2 driver class
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser not found: Will not load class
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser arbitrarily from one of
>   ModuleCL@16c14e7[org.netbeans.libs.xerces] and
>   ModuleCL@17e5fde[czsaw.project] starting from SystemClassLoader[406
>   modules]; see http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqModuleCCE

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the library that you loaded in the project libraries is the correct package for SAXBuilder. There seems to be a class ambiguity, and it is not sure which one to load.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the FAQ from Netbeans.

They designed the class loaders to fail if there are multiple modules causing ambiguity.

http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqModuleCCE

Like the article suggests, put this code in the module that should define the class to use:

Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(**YourClass**.class.getClassLoader());